# Response redirect from aspx old files to my new mvc project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have recently updated one of my sites to mvc 3 ,
My problem is that in any  search engine the results are www.mydoamin.com/mypage.aspx
I would like to set that any client that go to this url will be redirect to my home/index file ,
 How can I set it ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to read [this article](http://www.mycsharpcorner.com/Post.aspx?postID=40).

The main idea is to produce a HTTP 301 response code, which correspond to a permanent redirect.

Search engines like this, because they know the page is no longer here, but at the new address. It's also transparent for the user.

The challenge is sometimes to be able to map the old url to the new one... but it's the more clean way to move pages...